# How can I change the numbering of the headings in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Right now my document looks like this:

> 1. BIG HEADING   (heading 1)
>
>    1. Small Heading    (heading 2)

But I want it to be like this:

> ```
>  1. BIG HEADING
>    1.1 Small Heading
> ```

For some reason Word does not want to fix this for me. I have found that the layout I am looking for is in the multi-list section but I can only assign a numbering to a heading.

I have tried selecting my heading and then selecting the multi-list but that didn't change a thing.

Thanks

Comment: Side note: this is MS office 2010

Answer (score 1):

In Word, if you look at the multilevel list button it will have the option to do a drop-down.  From here you may define your own listing as to how you wish the format to be.

[image: Multilevel list screenshot in Word 2010]

Comment: +1.. you might want to post the image inline to avoid readers having to click through